# Can't merge pull request in AWS CodeCommit. Complains there are conflicts, but remote and local are up-to-date

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

CodeComit doesn't merge pull request. Says there conflicts, but local and remote branches are up-to-date.

I'm able to create PR fine - CodeCommit says branches are mergeable.
[image]

But when I click [Merge], it says there are conflicts.
[image]

And both branches, remote and local, are up-to-date.

What behavior is this? How to solve?

Comment: Are there realy no conflict? Try the merging locally and see if it runs successfully

Comment: I also face this problem. There are actually no conflicts, it's actually the commits that are behind. Github I think manages it in a much better way.

merging develop on my local into the branch and then pushing it again solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by squashing and pushing my branch with --force-with-lease.

It appears that CodeCommit can't always resolve branch and resolve merges whilst true git (tm) can

I.e.

```
commit c
|\
| commit b
|/
commit a
```

c won't merge

but

```
reset --soft b
add -A
commit -m "Same commit message"
push --force-with-lease
```

Does. The code in c hasn't changed but it's heritage has ...

Answer (score 1):

CodeCommit only support MergePullRequestsByFastForward now. Such a feature does not exist, at least yet. Every time The solution for this is to do "git pull origin master" locally and publish the branch again.